# ChartJS "Unable to get property 'getTime' of undefined or null reference"

Tags: java, jquery, chart.js

I'm trying to pass chart values from a java servlet to a web page.  The chart should display dates as x and integers as y.

The servlet sends an array of objects that contain year, month, day, and value.

The function:

```
function getMultiChart() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {formType: 'getProjection'},
        url: "ChartServlet",
        dataType: 'json',
        asynch: false,
        success: function (data) {
            var obj = JSON.stringify(data);
            var obj2 = JSON.parse(obj);
            var tmpArr = new Array();
            jQuery.each(obj2, function (prop, val){
                tmpArr.push("x: new Date(" + Number(val.year) + "," + Number(val.month) + "," + Number(val.day) + "), y: " + Number(val.value));
            });
            var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",{
                    title: {
                        text: "Manpower"
                    },
                    data: [
                        {
                            type: "column",
                            indexLabel: "{y}",
                            indexLabelPlacement: "outside",
                            indexLabelOrientation: "horizontal",
                            showInLegend: true,
                            name: "Overtime Personnel",
                            dataPoints: tmpArr
                        }
                    ]
                });
            chart.render();
       },
        error: function () {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

When I run it, I get the abovementioned error in ChartJS.js.

It works fine if I replace the json data with hard-coded values like:

```
var tmpArr = [
    {x: new Date(2020, 01, 1), y: 18},
    {x: new Date(2020, 01, 2), y: 0},
    {x: new Date(2020, 01, 3), y: 0},
    {x: new Date(2020, 01, 4), y: 0},
    {x: new Date(2020, 01, 5), y: 0},
    {x: new Date(2020, 01, 6), y: 0},
    {x: new Date(2020, 01, 7), y: 0},
    {x: new Date(2020, 01, 8), y: 0},
    {x: new Date(2020, 01, 9), y: 0},
    {x: new Date(2020, 01, 10), y: 0},
    {x: new Date(2020, 01, 11), y: 0},
    {x: new Date(2020, 01, 12), y: 0}
]
```

Where am I messing up here?

Comment: `tmpArr.push("x: new Date("` this appears to be a string, not an actual date value, or an object property

Comment: Why the double-shuffle with `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()`?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Because sometimes copying and pasting from your old code is not your friend.

Comment: @SterlingArcher: changing it to tmpArr.push("x: " + new Date(Number(val.year), Number(val.month), Number(val.day)) + ", y: " + Number(val.value)); gives me the same error.

Comment: `async` not `asynch`.

Comment: @BobStout, ha! Good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake is that the data array has to be an array of objects, not a string.

Even with this, I still couldn't get the "x: new Date(...)" part to work.

The working code is:

```
var tmpArr = new Array();
jQuery.each(obj2, function (prop, val) {
    var t = {y: val.value, label: val.month + "/" + val.day + "/" + val.year};
    tmpArr.push(t);
});
```